# JS Class and overriding the JQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, event-handling

This should be simple, but for reason I can't quite fathom it doesn't work and - more importantly - I can't find the right question to ask of Google!

What I want to do is prototype an event binder for a JS class as per below, what actually happens is nothing, unless I call .bind() directly on the box object.

```
function Box()
{
    this.Width = 200;
    this.Height = 200;
    this.WrapperClass = "boxWrapper";
    this.TitleClass = "boxTitle";
    this.ContentClass = "boxContents";
    this.Title = "This is a box";
    this.Content = "This is some box contents";
}

Box.prototype.Html = function()
{
    var box = $('<div></div>').addClass(this.WrapperClass);
    box.append($("<div></div>").addClass(this.TitleClass).append(this.Title));
    box.append($("<div></div>").addClass(this.ContentClass).append(this.Content));
    box.width(this.Width);
    box.height(this.Height);
    return box.outerHTML();
}

Box.prototype.Bind = function(event, eventDelegate)
{
    this.bind(event, eventDelegate);
}

function clickDelegate(message)
{
    alert(message);
}

$(document.ready(function() {
    var box = $(new Box().Html());
    box.Bind('click', clickDelegate('text'));
    $('body').append(box);
}
```

Comment: `box` is a jQuery object, which does not have a `.Bind` with capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append box before binding events.

I have created a [little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkzN3/4/) starting with your code and debugging it.

FYI : jQuery object has no method outerHTML, So I've embedded the newly created div in one other.

I've made several changes to your code that's why I'm not posting it here.

Comment: I should have said that outerHTML is a prototype function.. sorry!

Comment: That works, though I suspect my method would have worked as well had I noticed I was using Bind instead of bind!!  Thank you :)